# Routing indoor knowing steps

Tags: c#, algorithm, path, routes, dijkstra

I need to create a path in an indoor map having all the connections (steps, hops) 
 like `AB, BC, BA, CB, ...`. Suppose I have to go from `A` to `I` how will be the algorithm?
P.S. I'm developing in C# but any pseudo code or link to other resources is appreciated .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Breadth-First-Search (BFS) to construct a tree starting from `A`.

When you reach the node `I`, traverse the tree back up to the root (`A`) by repeatedly going up the parent node i.e. `I -> H -> G -> F -> C -> B -> A`.

As you do, you can retrieve the strings `HI, GH, FG, CF, BC, AB`, which you can then list backwards for your final solution.